# How can I measure the amount of time a process is opened?

Tags: windows-7, process, monitoring, timer

I would like to keep track of the amount of time a process is opened on Windows 7. Is there an utility that does this?

The process will be the process of a game or of an IM program. I want to program to:

- **If** 'process (Battlfield for example) opened' **and** 'last keystroke' < 60s **than** count.
- The counter doesn't reset when de process is closed, it just stops counting.
- The counter will be reset at night.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. A process is running even when you're not actively using it, so idle time bears no significance. Are you interested in the time (duration) you're actually using a process, when it's frontmost and you're actively using the computer?

Comment: Much better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) for this.

Comment: This is certainly a good option. Thanks. I think this will do the job.